# Ember PromiseArray sortBy

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

Okay, so I have a controller with it's model set to the following:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    myOtherProperty: attr(),
    mySortKey: attr(),
    mySubCollection: function () {
        return this.store.filter('MyOtherModel', function (myOtherModel) {
            //Some basic filtering logic (it's actually more complex than this)
            return myOtherModel.get('someProperty') == this.get('myOtherProperty');
        });
    }.property('myOtherProperty')
})
```

The actual filter function isn't important - what is important is that the 'mySubCollection' computed property returns a DS.PromiseArray object.  The controller for the above model is of type 'Ember.ObjectController' as it is only displaying a single object.

The template that displays this property uses an {{each}} helper to do so:

MyTemplate:

```
{{#each mySubCollection}}
    {{view App.MyView}}
{{/each}}
```

Now - I need to sort this promise array by the 'mySortKey' property *in descending order*.  How can I do this?  The documentation says that DS.PromiseArray extends from Ember.Array, but adding 'sortBy('mySortKey:desc')' at the end of the computed property for 'mySubCollection' causes it to break and not work at all - which makes sense because I would be calling 'sortBy' on a promise not an array.

I've looked at a bunch of different ideas and the one that keeps coming up is to switch to using an ArrayController.  I can do that, but it isn't ideal as it's adding a bunch of complexity on top of a pretty simple setup that works great already (aside from sorting).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't been quite able to figure out why `sortBy` doesn't work on the `PromiseArray`. But here's what I use as a workaround:

```
sortedCollection: function() {
    return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
        content: this.get('mySubCollection'),
        sortProperties: [this.get('mySortKey')],
        sortAscending: false
    });
}.property('mySubCollection', 'mySortKey')
```

Comment: I like this idea, and that's a nice way of showing mixins...thanks!  I'll give this a try and if it works I'll give you the answer

Comment: is this still the known way of doing things?

Comment: @Anthony Whether or not it's the best way of doing things, I don't know. But I know it still works and I still do it occasionally.

Comment: createWithMixins method is deprecated. Now it's Em.ArrayProxy.extend(Em.SortableMixin).create({ ... })

Answer (score 4):

Ember.SortableMixin has been deprecated, use [Ember.computed.sort](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort) instead.

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    myOtherProperty: attr(),
    mySortKey: attr(),
    mySubCollection: ...
    sortedCollection: Ember.computed.sort('mySubCollection', function(a, b){
        # compare logic
        return a.get('time') - b.get('time');
    }
})
```